# Oracle Error - Entity Framework - Multiple Include statements

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have multiple 'Include' with 'Select' statements on an Entity Framework Object:

```
var dbCustomers = conn.TCUSTOMERs
                      .Include(c => c.CodingTrees.Select(t => t.CodingVDNs))
                      .Include(c => c.CodingTrees.Select(t => t.CodingCategories))
                      .ToList();
```

I get this Oracle Exception:

```
Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 unterstützt APPLY nicht
```

Oracle doesn't support 'APPLY'.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I'm not an Oracle user, so sorry if this is unrelated, but have you looked at [Included Optimised](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-include-optimized) included in Entity Framework Plus?

Comment: Also, EF Core 5 has [split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries).

Answer (score 0):

My Workaround was

```
conn.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

conn.TCODINGCATEGORies.Load();
conn.TCODINGGROUPs.Load();
conn.TCODINGKEYs.Load();

dbCustomerList = conn.TCUSTOMERs.Include(c => c.CodingTrees.Select(t => t.CodingVDNs)).ToList();
```